# java.net.ConnectionException while trying to connect to local host

Tags: java, php, http, localhost, webserver

I set up a PHP server on `localhost:80`. However, when I tried to connect it with `HttpUrlConnection`, it threw an exception.

```
package test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /* Error thrown on the following line */
        new URL("http://localhost/").openConnection().connect(); 
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

The index.php is simply `<?php echo "Ello World"; ?>`

I've tried to access the page with Chrome and cURL, but that works perfectly

[image: Accessing the page by typing "http://localhost/"]

```
C:\Users\User>curl -XGET "http://localhost/"
Ello World
```

Then, I tried to send a GET request to google:

```
new URL("http://google.com/").openConnection().connect();
```

All good, no errors

I later searched for the related errors with the keywords "**ConnectException**", "**connection refused**", "**java localhost**" ..., still, no luck.

- The PHP server and Java is running on the same machine. No emulator. Just PHP and IntelliJ IDEA
- The PHP server doesn't receive any incoming request, because there is no log output
- I am using the HTTP protocol because the PHP server doesn't have SSL enabled
- Changing the URL to "http://localhost:80/", "http://127.0.0.1/" or "http://127.0.0.1:80/" doesn't help

My suspicion:

- PHP server doesn't accept requests with `URLConnection`, because they are incompatible
- `URLConnection` blocked HTTP request because it is "insecure"
- The firewall things is blocking the request, but as far as I known, firewall doesn't block connections within the same machine, Right?

Any Ideas?

Comment: It is not reproducible in my PC. I tested it using PHP 8.1.2. Do you have any proxy for your JVM?

Comment: You should check nothing else is using port 80 this can be used by applications like Skype, routers by default usually leave a TCP open for port 80 so try 8080

Answer (score 0):

According to the use case you described, the most probably reason would be that the firewall or some antivirus software is blocking your Java program, there is nothing that prevents the firewall to block connections within the same machine.

Please, and excuse me to say, but be sure as well that the server is actually running when the test is executed, perhaps it is terminated or stopped for any reason: I am saying this because it is strange that your test works successfully against `google.com` and not for `localhost`.

The PHP server will accept requests with `URLConnection`, at first glance there is nothing in the Java `HttpURLConnection` implementation that could cause such behavior, and `URLConnection` can connect to secure or insecure sites: take for instance the Google example you exemplified.

Finally, although I think there shouldn't be nothing wrong with using the `connect` method, try something different in your code, the web is plenty of examples of how to read some URL with `HttpURLConnection`. Take for instance this example, adapted from the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) - please, excuse the simplicity of the code:

```java
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
  
  String line;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
  }

  in.close();

  System.out.println("Response:\n" + response.toString());
} finally {
  urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

According to your comments, and the output from `curl` you provided:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
```

try including the same headers `curl` is already providing: as I mentioned in my comments, I have never experienced this behavior, but it could be of help. Please, try the following, for example:

```java
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
  // Note the headers provided: try to test it and see if it works
  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "localhost");
  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "curl/7.83.1");
  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
  
  String line;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
  }

  in.close();

  System.out.println("Response:\n" + response.toString());
} finally {
  urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I guess you are right. There is a button in PhpStorm which open the URL in chrome. When I click on it, it opened the page `http://localhost:63342/test-server/index.php?_ijt=some_token&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE`, despite that the Php server is listening at port 8080. When I tried to access `localhost:63342` through `URLConnection`, [a window similar to this](https://img-blog.csdn.net/20170328100927013?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQva3Nrc2ppcGVuZw==/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/SouthEast) popped out.

Comment: It turns out that it is [a security patch](http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions) that prevents unauthorized access. I suspect that this rule applies to all the ports as well. It worked when I accessed the URL I've mentioned previously (with the token as query parameters) using `URLConnection`. I suspect that Chrome and cURL have attached some authentication headers or something that PhpStorm accepts.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @iLittleWizard. I haven't hear about this matter before. Please, could you provide a screenshot of the Chrome developer tools when you access your server? Or, please, could you run curl in verbose mode (the `-v` flag) and provide the output obtained when you access your server? I think it could be of help.

Comment: Here is the output obtained by cURL in verbose mode: https://pastebin.com/sVhiuTr0

Comment: Thank you very much @iLittleWizard. I think there is nothing special about it, no redirections, no parameters... Please, could you try the suggestion provided in the answer and include certain headers? Honestly I don't remember if, by default, `HttpURLConnection` is setting some kind of header that could cause the error. If necessary, try using wireshark to trace the actual request or try enabling some kind of request tracing in your php page.